# Has any liberal theologian commented on the "Gay" movement explicitly becoming the "Pride movement?"

Tags: homosexuality, liberal-christianity, sodom, pride

When I was younger it was quite common to hear that the crimes of Sodom had nothing to do with gayness, but was about pride, and they would quote Ezekiel 16:49.

> Behold, this was the iniquity of thy sister Sodom, pride, fulness of
> bread, and abundance of idleness was in her and in her daughters,
> neither did she strengthen the hand of the poor and needy.

Has any liberal theologian commented on that verse and the change, for example, of "gay pride" month becoming simply "pride" month?

Comment: I think that many have  noticed this but publishing material in this area must be done carefully. Some may choose not to comment at all.

Comment: Christians generally consider "pride" to be a sin (e.g. "*pride goes before destruction*").  Generally the "Gay movement" is not made up of practicing Christians, so what words they choose to refer to themselves is hardly relevant to Christianity.